# Automatically extract data from an MS Excel spreadsheet and insert into table cells in an MS word document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a spreadsheet which I fill out as and when, with set data.

It is one row per entry.

I then have a single page MS Word document with a table that I have to insert that data in to.

I've searched for, and tried various techniques of taking the spreadsheet data and sticking it in to the word doc, but it never seems to work or turn out quite right. Normally formatting craps itself, or it just doesn't seem to update with the data.

Is there a way for me to automatically generate this word document from the spreadsheet? The data fields never change, it's the same cells from spreadsheet to the same cells in the word table every time, just the actual data itself that differs.

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please be more specific. What have you tried, and why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your needs correctly, you should be able to either copy and paste the data as a table to word (with no existing table) or merge the table into the existing table (which i assume is blank).  Just be sure to keep source formatting. Simply copy your data and right click in your word document for the option to keep the source format.

[image: Example 1: Copy and paste table to word]

[image: Example 2: Copy and paste data into an existing table]

Hope this helps